# Hierarchy trees in database and web app

Tags: postgresql, tree

I want to create web app which will use tree data structures. Users will be able to create, update and delete trees. I have the following table in PostgreSQL called nodes in database:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
parent_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCE nodes(id)
```

### Getting data

I want to get data in the following form:

```
id | name | children
---|------|--------------
 1 |    a | [2,3]
 2 |    b | []
 3 |    c | [4]
 4 |    d | []
```

I created query which returns data in form

```
id | name | parent_id
---|------|--------------
 1 |    a | 
 2 |    b | 1
 3 |    c | 1
 4 |    d | 3
```

And here is code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, name, parent_id, level) AS (
    SELECT nodes.id, nodes.name, nodes.parent_id, 0 AS level
    FROM nodes 
    WHERE name = 'a'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT nodes.id, nodes.name, nodes.parent_id, level+1
    FROM nodes 
    JOIN nodes_cte
    ON nodes_cte.id = nodes.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM nodes_cte;
```

Can I change SQL code to get what I want  or should I do that in app??

### Inserting data

I want to know what are the ways to insert data into the table. I think that following approach will work for me:

1. create sequence in database
2. increase sequence for number of elements in tree
3. manually compute ids in app and insert elements in the table

Are there better ways?

Comment: You don't need recursive here, you are only interested in one level of offspring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE nodes
        ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
        , name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , parent_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCES nodes(id)
        );


-- I created query which returns data in form
INSERT INTO nodes(id,name,parent_id)VALUES
 ( 1 , 'a' , NULL)
 ,( 2 , 'b' , 1)
 ,( 3 , 'c' , 1)
 ,( 4 , 'd' , 3)
        ;

SELECT p.id, p.name
        , array_agg(c.id) AS children
FROM nodes p
LEFT JOIN nodes c ON c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
 id | name | children 
----+------+----------
  1 | a    | {2,3}
  2 | b    | {NULL}
  3 | c    | {4}
  4 | d    | {NULL}
(4 rows)
```

---

Extra: using generate_series() to insert a bunch of records. Each record having id/3 as parent, (except when zero).

---

```
INSERT INTO  nodes(id,name,parent_id)
SELECT gs, 'zzz_'|| gs::text, NULLIF(gs/3 , 0)
FROM generate_series ( 5,25) gs
        ;
```

---

INSERTING/UPDATING DATA

Normally, your front-end should not mess with sequences, but leave that to the DBMS. You already have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `name`, because it is a **natural key** . So, your front-end should use that key to address rows in the nodes table, like in:

---

```
CREATE TABLE nodes2
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , parent_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCES nodes(id)
        );

INSERT INTO  nodes2(name,parent_id)
SELECT 'Omg_'|| gs::text, NULLIF(gs/3 , 0)
FROM generate_series ( 1,15) gs
        ;

PREPARE upd (text, text) AS
        -- child, parent
UPDATE nodes2 c
SET parent_id = p.id
FROM nodes2 p
WHERE p.name = $2 -- parent
AND c.name = $1   -- child
        ;

EXECUTE upd( 'Omg_12', 'Omg_11');
EXECUTE upd( 'Omg_15', 'Omg_11');
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 15
PREPARE
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
 id |  name  | children  
----+--------+-----------
  1 | Omg_1  | {3,4,5}
  2 | Omg_2  | {6,7,8}
  3 | Omg_3  | {9,10,11}
  4 | Omg_4  | {13,14}
  5 | Omg_5  | {NULL}
  6 | Omg_6  | {NULL}
  7 | Omg_7  | {NULL}
  8 | Omg_8  | {NULL}
  9 | Omg_9  | {NULL}
 10 | Omg_10 | {NULL}
 11 | Omg_11 | {15,12}
 12 | Omg_12 | {NULL}
 13 | Omg_13 | {NULL}
 14 | Omg_14 | {NULL}
 15 | Omg_15 | {NULL}
(15 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can i select root element of the tree? I'll have multiple trees in same database?

Comment: Root elements will have `parent_id IS NULL`

Comment: Sorry, for bad description, I meant how to select just nodes from single tree. But after 10 seconds, I figured it out. I can use your query in my recursive query to get that. Thank you for solving that.